# Using Parameters of One Request to Dynamically Change the Response of Another

Tags: templating, wiremock

I have been using response templating to give dynamic responses, given that all the  request and query parameters are associated with that request itself. However, I wanted to make a POST request with several parameters, and later use those parameters in a stubbed GET method's body response by using response templating. Is this something possible to do in wiremock? Any input is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: So, what have you tried? At [so] we help you with your technical difficulties. There is some effort expected on your part.

Comment: I have researched into response templating and transformations. From what I have found so far, neither are able to suffice my requirement. Templating assumes you have the parameters inside the request itself, and transformations allows to pass in external parameters unrelated to requests. What I want is to use a data of one request, incorporated to another. A sort of event sequencing, that the second request gives a valid response, only if the first request goes through and supplies some parameters that the second request can use.

Comment: Have you had a look at [Stateful Behaviour](http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/)?

Comment: @A. Kootstra, thank you for the follow up. I have indeed. From what I understood, stateful behaviour is helpful when you have the same end point, but want different responses in different scenarios. Here, however, I do have different endpoints, but wanted to use data from one of the request in another one. What I probably need to do is do a findAll() on the requests, find the one that matches with the request, and retrieve information from it. I will do more research along those lines. I was just wondering if somebody had encountered a similar issue and solved it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Storing state between requests is not a default feature of WireMock outside of mocking the behavior through [Stateful Behaviour](http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/), which is different from being actually stateful.

Without a custom plugin being able to share information between several requests is therefor not possible. In the WireMock documentation there is a section in the [documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#response-definition-transformation) on how to create such a plugin yourself. With a little development experience this is certainly doable.

On GitHub there are several plugin that create a storage mechanism to store information

- [WireMockCsv](https://github.com/massamany/WireMockCsv): store and retrieve information using HSQL Database.
- [wiremock-redis-extension](https://github.com/gustajz/wiremock-redis-extension) does something similar using Redis.

An alternative to these approaches is to create mappings/data just before the test starts. For example generating all the responses beforehand and then using Templated [BodyFileName](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#templated-body-file) tag to retrieve the just-in-time created file. Another way of achieving this result is to use the [Admin API](http://wiremock.org/docs/api/#tag/Stub-Mappings/paths/~1__admin~1mappings/post) to create the mappings themselves directly.